# Can I use silicone to glue drain gasket to drain before setting tub?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

I am about to set a bathtub onto an already installed drain.  Before moving the cast iron tub into place I need to first set a rubber washer on drain assembly.  Since there is very access and the tub is a beast,  I'd like to adhere the gasket in place before moving the tub.  Could a put a layer of silicone down under the gasket to glue it in place? [image][image]

Comment: On vehicles, you can use `gasket sealant` between a silicone gasket and a metal piece.  It holds the gasket in place, but never dries so you can reposition it.  I don't know if this could be used between silicon and whatever material your is.  Also of factor, an automotive gasket will be tightly compressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thin layer of silicone won't hurt but make sure it is evenly applied in case it takes longer to place the tub and pull the drain tight. Several houses back I was doing a remodel that the original owner used a thick layer and let it dry prior to installing the tub I don't know how many years before but it had a small leak and I had to replace two of the joists and some decking because of the leak, but a thin coating will help seal and hold it in place while setting the tub.